# Make get() returning a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to have `get()` returning a jQuery object instead of "just" the DOM element?

Example:

`$("div").get(0)` returns `[<div></div>]` instad of `<div></div>`.

I'd like to prevent overwrapping like `$($("div).get(0))` because the query will get a little bit longer than the example and I fear the readability gets lost. I'd rather not use variables to save unnecessary DOM elements in the RAM, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to return the jquery object instead of `get()`

```
$("div").eq(0)
```

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq()
>   method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that
>   set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the
>   set, [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 2):

You would use `eq`:

```
$("div").eq(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead , which will return jQuery object

```
$("div").eq(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try this also:

$('div:first')